# Dynamic XAML loading performance LoadModule

Tags: silverlight, xaml, dynamic-loading

We have a silverlight web application which has a configurable/customisable view.

Think iGoogle.

The user can add multiple tabular panels (telerik controls really) and configure them to display the information they want in the context the want.

Performance is not good enough.

Analysing with dotTrace performance we have 72 calls to the LoadComponent method:

```
        System.Windows.Application.LoadComponent(this, new System.Uri("/Company.Web.Portal.Views;component/Panels/TabularPanelContentView.xaml" +
                    "", System.UriKind.Relative));
```

The total execution time for these 72 calls is 11,465ms, 36.85% of the pause the user experiences in the UI becoming available. 30% of the time appears to be in the LoadComponent method calls, with a further 6.64% being in Telerik methods within that call tree.

So the loading of the Xaml and the creation of an object from that xaml appears to be the cost bottleneck.

Is there anyway to improve this? Surely loading from a url to the Xaml each time, parsing the xaml is expensive. Is there a best practices way to create multiple objects from the same xaml definition without this?

Comment: Are they all simultaneously loaded when the app starts?

Comment: We are switching them to load in parallel as much as possible, but 1/2s to instantiate an object from a XAML definition, given that that is the core of silverlight, seems to be ridiculous overhead.

Comment: The problem with that is that some of the telerik objects we use appear to need access to the UI thread, which means loading on a background worker fails.

Comment: You should be able to access the UI from a BGW no problem via the Dispatcher.BeginInvoke() method.